# Retrieved Cloudwatch logs out of order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We use AWS Cloudwatch Logs, and are retrieving a set of logs using AWS SDKs cloudwatch client's `filterLogEvents` function, and are pushing the logs to S3. For log groups with about 5000 events, we could see that the retrieved logs were out of order. For example, we would receive the logs till 11:35 UTC and the next log would be 14:42 UTC. We checked in cloudwatch and found that there were more logs between 11:35 UTC - 14:42 UTC. The logs during that time were present after a bunch of other logs.

I want to know why there is an inconsistency in the logs. Why are some set of logs obtained in the correct order, while some logs are placed somewhere else. All the logs seem to be present when we try to retrieve them, but the order for some of the logs is messed up.

Comment: What is the code that you're using to retrieve the events? Are you looping on the returned token?

Comment: we check if there's a next token, and if so parse the next set of events, retrieve all the events and push to s3. the logs are then taken from s3 to be shown in the ui.